# Can I select music/video that is in iTunes and play in my app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want to go the same way as UIImagePicker, is There any API I can use for Music/Video? I just want to pick one music/video, then play it in my app. Could someone tell me if there is an API for that? Thanks!

Comment: The logic behind this is, iTunes need to implement a method which opens your application. And do you recon Apple would do that?

Comment: So should I assume there is no way like UIImagePicker, right?

Comment: So hang on are you trying to access your music library or iTunes(iTunes is a store) and Music app is app which has your already downloaded songs.

Comment: what's the difference? downloaded songs? synced songs from iTunes? They All go into Music app? or Music app reads the music library?

Comment: on iPhone we have iTunes which is an app but it's a music store and another one is a Music app which is where you have your playlist and media player lol. Confusing because on Mac we only have iTunes which is a store and player

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, you are trying to access your media library which has already downloads music and videos. Than check below link which has a tutorial to walk you through about how to achieve that,

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-music-library-access/

Hope this will help!

Good luck!